# Inactive site collections

Tags: sharepoint-online, enterprise-search, retention

I am looking into archiving site collections based on use and the web property LastItemUserModifiedDate seems to be perfect.
However it seems like the property is not available in search and iterating the 300.000 site collections might be a slow proces.
I wonder if the managed property Lastmodifiedtimeforretention is just another alias for LastItemUserModifiedDate, but I can't find any documentation about that property.
Any ideas how to locate the site collections without any user updates within the last x days?

[image]

I have pulled some data from a production tenant and it looks like Lastmodifiedtimeforretention in most cases is the same as Created date :-( AND it looks like LastItemModified isn't a good indicator either.

Answer (score 1):

Just poking around at my sites it looks like `Lastmodifiedtimeforretention<1/1/2019 ContentClass=STS_Site` might get you close.

Comment: Close only counts in horse shoe and hand granates ;-) It seems like Lastmodifiedforretention often is set at creation time so the result set will contain a large number of sites that has been Modified resently.

Comment: Then you need to find another date to use.

Comment: Either that or check web. LastItemUserModifiedDate in a number of parallel processes without getting throttled. I am surprised that LastItemUserModifiedDate is not available through Search but perhaps MS Graph is an option

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, to get the site collections without any user updates within the last x days.

Using

Lastmodifiedtime<(special date) AND ContentClass=STS_Site

Comment: Hi Lisa, so Lastmodifiedtime and LastItemUserModifiedDate are identical in your environment ?

Comment: LastItemModifiedtime and LastItemUserModifiedDate are not identical. The latter property was added later by Microsoft to reflect changes made by user accounts only. The former property was influenced by changes made by the system.                  You can use PowerShell to list all SharePoint sites in your Office 365 tennant with the LastItemUserModifiedDate:   https://alexholmeset.blog/2017/09/03/sharepoint-lastitemmodifieddate/